# Is there equivalent to feature datasets supported by PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, feature-dataset

I am currently planning the migration of a database from ArcSDE/ ArcMap to PostGIS / QGIS.

The data is stored in raster catalogues and feature datasets.

Is there an equivalent to feature datasets supported by PostGIS or do I need to group the layers by adding a prefix corresponding to the current feature dataset?

Comment: we use naming conventions and schemas to accomplish organizing of datasets...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there is no feature dataset analog in Postgis. But you can use database schemas for grouping data

Comment: Hi megadrofan, welcome to GIS.SE, and thanks for contributing. :) This answer would be improved by elaborating on or linking to examples of using db schemas for grouping. Generally speaking we try to avoid one liners, in an effort to build a knowledge base that will be useful in the long haul.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know there is no implementation in posgis as it stands. I did find some ERDs in the esri web help that would let someone with more knowledge than me code up feature sets but I will need to just look carefully ar layer naming conventions for my migration.